# A menu block won't show up for second language

Tags: routes, blocks

I have 3 separate menus in my header. They are not connected. I don't used secondary menus.

My site is bilingual: english + spanish.

All 3 are created using menus and placed in the same region using blocks. They are all translatable: checked Make this block translatable. And they all have translated strings edited already.

However, when I switch to Spanish one of the menu dissapears and won't show up. I check in the DOM and is not build at all.

Another mention: the menu that won't show up is a category menu: it points to the a page that display article based on the specific category.

Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: I found a solution, anyone interested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific menu edit mode: structure/menu/manage/your-menu/edit alter the Translation Mode.